# Re-writing a private method in Java makes no difference to code output. Why?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I tested the following code in Java to see what happens when I rewrite the implementation of a private method.

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */

class Superclass {

    public void runDo() {
        this.doSomething();
    }

    private void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("from Superclass");
    }
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {

    private void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("from Subclass");
    }

}

class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Superclass superSuper = new Superclass();
        Superclass superSub = new Subclass();
        Subclass subSub = new Subclass();

        superSuper.runDo();
        superSub.runDo();
        subSub.runDo();
    }
}
```

The output for the above sample is

> from Superclass
>
> from Superclass
>
> from Superclass

While I expected something like

> from Superclass
>
> from Subclass
>
> from Subclass

Can someone please explain this behaviour and why it makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** override a private method.  You must declare it default, protected or public for the behaviour that you want.

I suggest reading the Java documentation on [access modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 1):

**It does not work because you cannot override `private` methods.**

You did not actually override your method. In `Superclass` you render `doSomething()` as `private`, hence it is not visible (nor overridable) in children classes.

Try setting access modifier to `protected`, `public` or `default`.